# How to use greater than Symbol > as part of the string

Tags: string

I want to create string that has greater than symbol as part of the concatenation.

```
declare @maxWeek int = 53 
declare @weekno int = 4
declare @mysql varchar(max)

set @mysql = 'select CASE WHEN ' + @weekno + > + @maxWeek + ' THEN @maxWeek Else @weekNo END'

exec (@mysql)
```

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near '>'.

Comment: '>', make it a string if you want to concatenate it with strings.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: I already did made it '>' still getting the error.. Im doing this in SQL Server

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'select CASE WHEN ' to data type int.

here is the error when I put '>'

Comment: You cannot concatenate `varchar` and `number` in sql server without conversion. use `... + convert(nvarchar(max), @weekno) + ...`